# Real part of a complex inner product is zero implies the imaginary part is also zero - why?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

[This very useful](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Edav/spectral.pdf) discussion/proof of the spectral theorem states one thing that still confuses me - as an instrumental part of their proof, they suggest that for any self-adjoint linear operator $S$ on a finite vector space $V$, the following hold:

First defining:
$$\varphi(v)=\langle S(v),v\rangle\\v_0=\operatorname{argmax}\varphi(v),v\in V:\langle v,v\rangle=1$$

I hope my notation was correct there - $\varphi$ attains a maximum on the unit sphere at $v_0$, is what that is trying to say.

They then prove the first line of the following, which I'm happy with, but assume the second line - which I'm *not* happy with!

$$\langle v_0,u\rangle=0\implies\Re\langle S(v_0),u\rangle=0\\\Re\langle S(v_0),u\rangle=0\implies\langle S(v_0),u\rangle=0$$

Is it true in general that if a complex inner product has zero real part, it is necessarily zero? Or is this simply a detail to do with the particular definitions of $S$ ($S$ as self-adjoint, or linear perhaps?), $v_0$ and $u$?

Comment: Well, $<i,1>=i \ne 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *not* claiming that $\operatorname{Re}\langle S(v_0),u\rangle$ implies $\langle S(v_0),u\rangle=0$.  Instead, they actually explain how they are deducing that $\langle S(v_0),u\rangle=0$, namely by applying the first line "to all the vectors $e^{i\theta}u$".  Or, more simply, since $e^{i\theta}u$ is just some $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination of $u$ and $iu$, we will just use it for $iu$.  In other words, suppose that $$\langle v_0,u\rangle=0.$$  Then we also know that $$\langle v_0,iu\rangle=0.$$  But now we can apply the first line with $iu$ in place of $u$ to deduce that $$\operatorname{Re}\langle S(v_0),iu\rangle=0.$$ Now $\langle S(v_0),iu\rangle=-i\langle S(V_0),u\rangle$ so its real part is just the imaginary part of $\langle S(v_0),u\rangle$.  So we know not only that the real part of $\langle S(v_0),u\rangle$ is $0$ but also that its imaginary part is $0$, so $\langle S(v_0),u\rangle=0$.

(This is a common trick: you prove a fact about all vectors, and then you apply that fact to all the different scalar multiples of one particular vector to reach a stronger conclusion about that one vector.)

Answer (score 1):

(1.11) states
$$\langle v_0, u \rangle = 0 \implies \Re \langle Sv_0, u \rangle = 0.$$
We will apply (1.11) multiple times to obtain the stronger result
$$\langle v_0, w \rangle = 0 \implies \langle Sv_0, w \rangle = 0.$$

---

Let $w$ be some vector and
suppose $\langle v_0, w \rangle = 0$. Let $u = e^{i\theta} w$. Then $\langle v_0, u \rangle = \overline{e^{i\theta}} \langle v_0 , w \rangle = 0$. Applying (1.11) implies
$$0 = \Re \langle Sv_0, u \rangle = \Re (\overline{e^{i\theta}} \langle Sv_0, w \rangle)
= \cos(\theta) \Re\langle Sv_0, w \rangle
+ \sin(\theta) \Im\langle Sv_0, w \rangle.$$
This holds for any choice of $\theta$, so we must have $\Re \langle Sv_0, w \rangle = \Im \langle Sv_0, w \rangle  = 0$. (Or as Eric Wofsey demonstrates, it suffices to check $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \pi/2$.)

Comment: Thank you also for your answer; shouldn't it be $-\sin(\theta)\Im\langle S(v_0),u\rangle$? The complex conjugate should negate the imaginary part

Comment: @FShrike There is one minus sign from $\Re(ab) = \Re(a) \Re(b) - \Im(a) \Im(b)$, and another from $\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't true in general that if a complex inner product has zero real part, it is necessarily zero:

$<(i, i)^T, (1,1)^T> = (-i, -i)(1,1)^T = -2i$.